# Auth redirects to SController

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I have a few controllers, for example 'blogs' and 'users', if I go to 'blogs/add' I get redirected to the auth login page, when I login I should get back to 'blogs/add', but I get redirected to 's/add' instead!

This doesn't happen when I try the same thing but with the users controller or with any other controller.

As far as I can see there are no strange functions in the blogs controller, I just baked it with 'cake bake controller blogs scaffold' and didn't change anything.

Comment: edit1 added. if that does not suffice remove the $scaffold from the controller and bake it again, tell me what happened.

Comment: @benjamin yes i did that, and there is no $scaffold variable, when you bake your app with 'scaffold' it creates all crud actions (index, view, edit...). i think it's weird to:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my project was named "blog" and apparently you can't name your project the same as your controller ("blogs"). It's an bug in the Auth component wich doesn't redirect right, you can just rename your project to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined any custom routes? ( in /app/config/routes.php )

Comment: i didn't create any custom routes, even tried to remove the default ones!